# Any idea how to make a notification of twitch bans like StreamerBans for a twitter bot?

Tags: node.js, twitch-api

I want to create a twitter bot on node.js that notifies about bans / unbans and streams on twitch but I do not know how I have seen several "tutorials" but none shows any way, I am not very experienced in this and it is my first time working with Twitch Api and Twitter Api

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are familiar with how API works in general and this is to be designed for your own channel, first I would recommend reviewing the Twitch API documentation at https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api#introduction to learn how to get started with your app.

Once you have your client-ID and Oath2 token you will be better prepared for learning to use the API calls to gather the information you're looking to pull.

For banned users there are two ways you can pull this information with the following requests:

`GET https://api.twitch.tv/helix/moderation/banned`

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-banned-users

and

`GET https://api.twitch.tv/helix/moderation/banned/events`

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-banned-events

Depending on the amount of information you want to gather will determine which requests you want to use.

I hope this helps in your ventures.

Comment: There is a problem only and it returns in a single channel and not on a streamer: c

Comment: If you're looking for bans from Twitch there is no API end-point to detect that. When twitch bans an account they remove it from listing and view so trying to gather information on a channel that has been banned by Twitch would show as 404 and any requests from API would show the same. The website you referenced gathers viewers on a timer and logs them to check later. If the request pulls a 404 from an existing account in their database they mark it as banned.